# Can't use .update() function on Django context in views?

Tags: python, django

I have a function that gets some base information in my `views.py` file, and I'm trying to update the context of each page using it by having it return a dictionary. However, using `.update()` on the context dictionary in the `render()` function doesn't seem to work.

Here's what I'm doing:

```
def getBaseInfo():
    allPages = list(Page.objects.all())
    primaryPages = allPages[:5]
    secondaryPages = allPages[5:]
    return {'p':primaryPages, 'p2':secondaryPages}

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'pages/index.html', {}.update(getBaseInfo()))
```

However, nothing is sent to my templates. Thanks in advance!

Edit: I'm using Python 2.7.11

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=update#dict.update
Note the: "Return `None`" part. Python is not javascript, the update method does not return a dict and what you're doing makes no sense. Why don't you simply pass along the `getBaseInfo()` as context?

Comment: @Wolph, I didn't know that .update() returns `None`! Thanks for that. I can't pass `getBaseInfo()` as context because my Django app uses Python 2, which doesn't allow for updating a dictionary by returning values within the dictionary (`{getBaseInfo()}` does not become `{'p':[], 'p2':[]}`, it 's just a dictionary that has a key without a value)

Comment: `{getBaseInfo()}` does not become `{'p':[], 'p2':[]}` but `getBaseInfo()` does. `getBaseInfo()` already returns a dictionary so there is no need to convert it. It can be used as the context straight away

Comment: And there is no difference between Python 2 and Python 3 here. `return render(request, 'pages/index.html', getBaseInfo())` works fine in both versions.

Comment: @Wolph Right, but I have other views that I want to send other info with. For example, if I have a `shows` view where I want to add `'show':showObject` to the context, I can't do that if I exclusively pass `getBaseInfo()` as the context. I'm trying to make it so I can add whatever I want to the context, and then add `p` and `p2` in. Since I have many views where I want to pass `p` and `p2` through, I'd rather keep the code that loads them in `getBaseInfo()`. The most important part is being able to pass things in addition to getBaseInfo()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, if you wanted to use a base dictionary and add objects to that you should do so explicitly:

```
def index(request):
    context = getBaseInfo()
    context.update({'otherkey': 'othervalue'})
    # or
    context['otherkey'] = 'othervalue'
    return(...)
```

However, there is no need to do this at all. Django already provides you a way of automatically providing shared context, and that is a [context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext).

In fact your `getBaseInfo()` function is *already* almost a context processor - it just needs to accept the `request` parameter - so you just need to add it to the `context_processors` list in your TEMPLATES setting. Then *all* your templates will automatically get the values from that function.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about context processors! I'm new to Django and still learning - this seems like exactly what I needed!

Comment: I'm stuck on something fairly similar, basically filtering my context dictionary but so far I have yet to be able to update the variables based on the search criteria. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61973937/django-filter-queryset-show-variables-on-template

Answer (score 1):

You should do something like this:

```
def index(request):
    allPages = list(Page.objects.all())
    primaryPages = allPages[:5]
    secondaryPages = allPages[5:]
    return render(request, 'pages/index.html', {'p':primaryPages, 'p2':secondaryPages})
```

Other option should be to make `getBaseInfo` a `@property` for reusability and DRY purposes, or make the view class based template view and define reusable code as mixin. I prefer the latter, but it's entirely matter of personal choice.