# django filter queryset show variables on template

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-filter

Below is the views.py to my stats page. This page has a bunch of calculations based on my model objects. Works great. However when I apply [django-filter](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to the data it does not change. Example filtering for only "short" trades or in the "last 7 days".

I know that get_context_data is basically hardcoding the results and it will not be affected by any filter query. This is not the approach but I've tried several things with no results so back to square one... How would I do this?

I've tried `kwargs.update` and `context.update` but also was not getting results.

This seems like it should be super obvious as how else do people show and filter statistics on objects?

views.py

```
class StatsView(LoginRequiredMixin, FilterView):
    model = Trade
    template_name = 'dashboard/stats.html'
    filterset_class = StatsFilter

    def get_form(self, *args, **kwargs):
        form = StatsFilter()
        user = self.request.user
        form.fields['associated_portfolios'].queryset = Portfolio.objects.filter(user=user)
        return form

    def get_max_consecutive_wins(self, data):
        longest = 0
        current = 0
        for num in data:
            if num > 0:
                current += 1
            else:
                longest = max(longest, current)
                current = 0

        return max(longest, current)

    def get_max_consecutive_loses(self, data):
        longest = 0
        current = 0
        for num in data:
            if num < 0:
                current += 1
            else:
                longest = max(longest, current)
                current = 0

        return max(longest, current)

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        trade = Trade.objects.filter(user=self.request.user, status='cl').order_by('created')
        all_trades = Trade.objects.filter(user=self.request.user, status='cl').count()
        context = super(StatsView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        data = [t.profit_loss_value_fees for t in trade]

        win_trades_count = [t.trade_result for t in trade].count('win')
        loss_trades_count = [t.trade_result for t in trade].count('loss')
        scratch_trades_count = [t.trade_result for t in trade].count('scratch')

        avg_win = 0 if win_trades_count == 0 else mean(t.profit_loss_value_fees for t in trade if t.trade_result == 'win')
        avg_loss = 0 if loss_trades_count == 0 else mean(t.profit_loss_percent for t in trade if t.trade_result == 'win')
        avg_win_percent = 0 if win_trades_count == 0 else mean(t.profit_loss_percent for t in trade if t.trade_result == 'win')
        avg_loss_percent = 0 if loss_trades_count == 0 else mean(t.profit_loss_percent for t in trade if t.trade_result == 'loss')

        context['all_trades'] = all_trades
        context['gross_profit'] = sum([t.profit_loss_value for t in trade])
        context['net_profit'] = sum([t.profit_loss_value_fees for t in trade])
        context['win_trades_profit'] = sum(
                t.profit_loss_value_fees for t in trade if t.trade_result == 'win')
        context['loss_trades_profit'] = sum(
                t.profit_loss_value_fees for t in trade if t.trade_result == 'loss')
        context['win_trades_count'] = win_trades_count
        context['loss_trades_count'] = loss_trades_count
        context['scratch_trades_count'] = scratch_trades_count
        context['win_trades_count_ratio'] = win_trades_count / all_trades * 100
        context['loss_trades_count_ratio'] = loss_trades_count / all_trades * 100
        context['scratch_trades_count_ratio'] = scratch_trades_count / all_trades * 100
        context['total_fees'] = sum([t.get_fees() for t in trade])
        context['avg_win'] = avg_win
        context['avg_loss'] = avg_loss
        context['avg_win_percent'] = avg_win_percent
        context['avg_loss_percent'] = avg_loss_percent
        context['avg_position_size'] = mean(t.position_size for t in trade)
        context['largest_winning_trade'] = max([t.profit_loss_value_fees for t in trade])
        context['largest_losing_trade'] = min([t.profit_loss_value_fees for t in trade])
        context['largest_winning_trade_percent'] = max([t.profit_loss_percent for t in trade])
        context['largest_losing_trade_percent'] = min([t.profit_loss_percent for t in trade])
        context['max_consecutive_wins'] = self.get_max_consecutive_wins(data)
        context['max_consecutive_loses'] = self.get_max_consecutive_loses(data)
        context['qs'] = Trade.objects.filter(user=self.request.user, status='cl').order_by('created')

        return context
```

Answer (score 0):

The first problem, like you pointed, is that you are hard-coding the results in the `get_context_data()`. The `FilterView` ClassBasedView inherits from the [MultipleObjectsMixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/) mixin of Django, so you should take both into account. I assume from your issues that you are not using the `object_list` property in your template - that's where the CBV populates the data.

Basically, in your current view, the flow will go as:

- get the queryset based in the `get_queryset()` method.
- If this doesn't exist, it will use the `queryset` property defined
- In last case, the `model`. <-- This is your case, so it will use `Trade.objects.all()`
- the FilterSet is applied to the original queryset
- paginate (if you have it configured) and assign the filtered queryset to the `object_list` in the context.

So, some changes you can start trying:

- Use the `object_list` to perform the stats calculation in your `get_context_data()` instead of querying for the `Trade` model yourself.
- If you are always going to filter the results based in the current user, you can use the `get_queryset()` method to apply that filter from there, so you would do:

  ```
  def get_queryset(self):
      qs = super().get_queryset()
      return qs.filter(user=self.request.user, status='cl')
  ```
- I would also recommend you to look at Django's built-in [data aggregation mechanisms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/aggregation/), as it would make all those calculations at DB level. If your start to treat big amounts of data, making all this manual processing is going to be an issue.

I think those points would be a good start!

Comment: Hey @jjoseba thanks for the answer attempt. Been trying to find a solution based on your feedback but still not results. It's weird this is so tricky as it seems like a very common situation to want to queryset ones get_context. Maybe I'm wrong. I think I'll start linking into a solution by moving the statistics into the mode.

Comment: Without seeing the whole picture is difficult to help you further... I suggest that you read carefully the class-based views documentation and the `django-filter` docs and start with a small example: just a listview with a model where you filter based in one field. Once you get that working, try to extend it to your actual problem. Good luck!